# Fluid dynamics problem of hydrostatic equilibrium

Tags: fluid-dynamics

The problem is to calculate the force per unit width and the torque per unit width about the bottom of a lock gate which is produced when a fluid of depth $H$ and density $\rho$ lies at rest on one side of the gate, and fluid of depth $h<H$ and density $\rho$ lies at rest on the other side of the gate.

How great is this force if the depths of water are $1m$ and $3m$, and the gates are $3m$ wide. ( i know the answer to this is $120,00 N$).

I have manged to achieve an equation for the force $F=\frac{1}{2}\rho g(H_{1}^2-H_{2}^2)$ however when i substitute $H_{1}^2=9$ and $H_{2}^2=1$ i don't seem to get the force as $F=120,000$ N as required. so i'm stuck if anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: Please provide a picture to the problem.

Comment: Hello, See problem 6 on the following website http://www.star.uclan.ac.uk/~tvc/publicfiles/MA3842/problemsheets/qs1.pdf

Comment: bump please help this is difficult for me